# Zend Framework and Couch DB

Tags: php, zend-framework, couchdb

Does Zend Framework has native Couch DB support? I found only Zend_Couch by Matthew Weier O'Phinney.

- http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Couch+-+Matthew+Weier+O'Phinney

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. The proposal is Ready for Review, so it likely end up in ZF sooner or later.
You can either wait or use [PHPillow](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/phpillow_php_couchdb_wrapper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but there are a few libraries available out there already. I personally like  http://www.saggingcouch.com  because it's simple and light weight (disclaimer: I developed it, so feedback is welcome).