# NoSQL solution for Zend Framework?

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework, couchdb, nosql

I'm looking to use a NoSQL solution(CouchDB/MongoDB/etc) for a Zend Framework based site I'm building.  Can anyone give me any pointers on implementation or guide me somewhere to help me get started?

Use-case would be a data tagging solution tied around a user management system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [Zend Framework: Zend_Couch Component Proposal](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Couch+-+Matthew+Weier+O%27Phinney) for working with CouchDB and may be in Zend Framework 2.0

There is also this thread that may help out. [Zend Framework and Couch DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247368/zend-framework-and-couch-db)

Comment: from my research it looks like couchdb is the way to go.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

PHP has builtin mongo stuff, but it's not very great... Take a look at a library called [Shanty](https://github.com/coen-hyde/Shanty-Mongo) - I forked my own version of his lib as a starting point for my own.

Comment: gnarf, Shanty-Mongo definitely makes it really simple to work with mongoDB when working with PHP (and Zend Framework too)

Answer (score 2):

Consider evaluating [membase](http://www.membase.org/), it uses the standard Memcached protocol for client-server communication, so you don't need any client lib other than php-memcached.

Comment: @John Cartwright, Membase is not memcache, it just uses the same protocol. Membase uses a persistent storage.

Answer (score 1):

First describe what your actually usecase is and what your requirements are. 
Searching for a noSQL solution without providing facts is a pretty pointless question since every noSQL DB has its pros and cons.

http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Comment: usercase would be a data tagging solution tied around a user management system.  I'll update my question